# Invoking `super` in classmethod called from metaclass.__new__

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have a case where my class has a custom metaclass, which calls a class method of the class when creating it, something like:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        ...
        new_class = super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        ...
        new_class.get_fields() # do something
        ...
        return new_class

class FooBar(object):
    __metaclass__ = Metaclass

    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls):
        ...
```

(Example of such code is in [Tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie).)

The problem is if I want to do:

```
class NewBar(FooBar):
    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls):
        super(NewBar, cls).get_fields()
        ...
```

This does not work because `NewBar` is not yet created at the point `super` is invoked (program flow is still in metaclass). So, is there any workaround?

I know that probably `get_fields` method could become a method of metaclass, but this would make inheritance much harder to implement (you would have to define both new metaclass and class itself, not nice to developers wanting to extend this classes).

(Python 2.7.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `NewBar` can be unavailable when `get_fields` is invoked, you can still find it in the MRO of `cls`:

```
@classmethod
def get_fields(cls):
    # we can get invoked before NewBar is available in globals,
    # so get NewBar from cls.__mro__
    NewBar = next(c for c in cls.__mro__
                  if c.__module__ == __name__ and c.__name__ == 'NewBar')
    super(NewBar, cls).get_fields()
    ...
```

Although this code looks funny, it works correctly and is significantly simpler than the alternatives proposed in the question. While most calls to `super` with a non-constant first argument (such as unqualified `super(cls, cls)`) are incorrect and break inheritance, this one is safe because the generator expression is nothing but an unconventional way to get a hold of `NewBar`.

When looking for the clas in the MRO we check for both class and module name (available as `__name__`, [as pointed out by Mitar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757468/calling-class-method-from-metaclass-and-inheritance/12757752#comment17251140_12757752)) to avoid a false positive if `othermodule.NewBar` inherits from `thismodule.NewBar`.

Comment: I ended up using: `me = next(c for c in cls.__mro__ if c.__module__ == __name__ and c.__name__ == 'NewBar')`.

Comment: I love the `c.__module__ == __name__` improvement! I'll update the answer.

Comment: What about `try: super_class = NewBar; except NameError: super_class = cls; super(super_class, cls).get_fields()`?

Comment: @kroolik It would work, but it is obfuscated in a different way. The code in the answer makes it clear that we're simply trying to find `NewBar` in order to call `super` in the most regular possible way. In your variant the `super` invocation appears even more magical than necessary.

Comment: A third variant such as `try: NewBar; except NameError: NewBar = cls; ...` would retain the `NameError` trick, but making it clear that we're really looking for `NewBar`. It'd still make me queasy that it doesn't *ensure* it actually found `NewBar`. Perhaps an `assert cls.__name__ == 'NewBar`` would be in order there.

Comment: Indeed we cannot be certain that `cls` in `except:` is `NewBar`, but we have 2 cases: call from our metaclass (`NewBar.__metaclass__`) - here `NewBar` hasn't finished construction thus isn't available as a global name and `cls` is the `NewBar` class object. Second - `NewBarDeriving.__metaclass__`, here we are constructing a class that is deriving from `NewBar`, thus NewBar is a valid identifier unless someone creates a new class inside `NewBar.__metaclass__` etc. But that's sorcery, not programming. The `assert` is fine as in notifies the coder that something is screwed up.

Comment: The `next()` variant isn't guaranteed to find the desired class, to be honest (think of `NewBar.get_fields.im_func(<my_evil_class>, fields, excludes)`), but might cause unexpected behaviour whilst `try: except: assert` is self-explaining.

Comment: @kroolik The pathological examples of calls to `get_fields` are fortunately not on the table, as we know exactly how `get_fields` is called. (`The `MetaClass` is in reality defined inside the tastypy framework.) The answer needs to pick the least, as you put it, sorcerous solution, and that's sometimes a matter of taste. You can simply submit your code as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from @user4815162342 I found even simpler solution:

```
try:
    super(NewBar, cls).get_fields()
except NameError, e:
    if 'NewBar' in str(e):
        super(cls, cls).get_fields()
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Simpler at the expense of correctness, unfortunately. In particular, `'NewBar' in str(e)` feels like a bug waiting to happen, especially as this kind of code needs to be in every overridden implementation of `get_fields`. For the sake of future maintenance of that code, I would seriously recommend a cleaner approach.

Comment: Hm, yes, but I cannot change original `get_fields` method. It is from external library.

Comment: I see. This wasn't clear from your example because `FooBar`, the first to define `get_fields`, already uses your metaclass, so it was reasonable to assume that `FooBar`, and the entire `get_fields` interface, was defined by you.

Comment: So, is the metaclass under your control? If so, I think I can modify my answer to work without changing the signature of `get_fields`.

Comment: Maybe I should provide a direct link to code in [Tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1533).

Comment: Or... you can replace the try/except logic with `me = NewBar if 'NewBar' in globals() else cls` and then call `super` with `super(me, cls).get_fields()`. Still a bit hackish, but way simpler than my proposal, and reasonably easy to follow.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a third solution, which is to just look for `NewBar` in `cls.__mro__`. That one seems least ugly—no fussing with `globals` in any form—but it still requires string-based search through MRO.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is specific to python 2.7, however, for those using python 3.6 you can simply call `super()`.

```py
class NewBar(FooBar):
    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls):
        super().get_fields()
        ...
```